# AWS CloudFormation chaining functions

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have a template which is a Master Stack for our product. I'm in the process of changing all templates from JSON to YAML, employing the new "!if" type functionality. I originally had the troublesome part of my template look as follows (this works in JSON):

```
"CreateProdResources" : {"Fn::And" : [{"Fn::Not" : [{"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "Environment"}, "beta"]} ]}, {"Fn::Not" : [{"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "Environment"}, "eubeta"]} ]} ]}
```

I want to change this to YAML, so this portion of the template now looks like this:

`CreateProdResources:
    !And:
    - !Not:
      - !Equals:
        - Ref: Environment
        - beta
    - !Not:
      - !Equals:
        - Ref: Environment
        - eubeta`

Cloud formation is throwing a YAML not well-formed error, because of the chained ! functions inside of a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To chain YAML AWS CloudFormation functions, just do as follows:

```
CreateProdResources:
  !And
  - !Not
    - !Equals [!Ref "Environment", "beta"]
  - !Not
    - !Equals [!Ref "Environment", "eubeta"]
```

Comment: [This](http://www.yamllint.com/), [this](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) and [this](http://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator) online YAML parsers/checkers as well as my python parser indicate this is invalid YAML. Are you sure you are not missing some indentation on the 2nd-last line?

Comment: everything under the "CreteProdResources" line should be over two spaces to the right.